# Login mysql via mysql-workbench or mysql-query-browser with phpmyadmin access only

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

I have access to the database only through phpmyamdin. What can I do to log in via mysql-query-browser or mysql-workbench? I enter my password, username and host to mysql-workbench but there is no connection.

Thank you.

Comment: Error message:Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at xx.xx.xxx.xx:3306:
  Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not get an error any message, it sounds like there may be a firewall blocking the request on port 3306.  You may also need to ask for privileges for the user/pwd that you are logging into from the host machine you are logging into.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that mysql is only listening in localhost, so you can't access it with any program that's not on the same machine as the mysql server (and phpmyadmin can access it because it's on the same server).